# How to add Function into Gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a Gridview contain button

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server">

 <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <button type="button">Click me</button>                      
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and I want to add bootstrap Modal

how can I add Onclick Function inside Gridview to push the bootstrap Modal

Thx

Comment: Since you have a HTML `<button>` you can add a click event to that in the normal way using Javascript (if you don't know, you can look up examples in dozens of places online). The GridView is actually pretty irrelevant to that really.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below example. What I am doing here is creating a GridView, which has 2 columns. The second column is button. When you click on the button, the Modal is shown displaying the value.

Note: I'm not showing the GridView bindings here which are the server-side. I assume you are aware of those.

This is the Aspx. You don't need much to do here. `Aspx + Bootstrap` is very powerful and does the most

```
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview11" runat="server">
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <label id="lblItem" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("ItemId")%>'></label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<%#Eval("ItemId")%>">Click on '<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'</button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

This is the Bootstrap Modal part. Well, I usually get this from the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) as per my requirement

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the last is the Javascript/JQuery that triggers the Modal

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal',
            function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // this is where the button is triggering the modal
                var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // reading a value form the triggered button
                var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to the person ' + recipient); // assigning a new value,which will be displayed on the Modal title
            });
    </script>
```

I hope this helps, Let me know if you have any question or feedback.

Comment: I dont know how can I put all this codes in my code

Comment: This is very basic Asp.Net and Js. If you are very new to web and programming, before you start with Gridview, you must learn other core components https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_intro.asp.